# Yocto Extensible SDK (eSDK) and CMake

Tags: cmake, yocto

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964891/yocto-sdk-with-cmake-toolchain-file) is about getting `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)` in a CMakeLists.txt file to work in a Yocto SDK.

I have the same question but for a Yocto Extensible SDK.

CMake finds the compiler and linker just fine, but doesn't know where to find packages, such as Boost. I get messages such as
    Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

```
Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
Boost's headers.
```

The answer to the other question doesn't seem to apply to extensible SDKs.

Comment: In other words, the question is **how to get CMake toolchain** file for eSDK, doesn't it? This is just for clarification.

Comment: Yes, but ideally this would be transparent to my developers. I would love for it to "Just Work."