# Native development on Variscite Yocto Rocko SOM

Tags: cmake, yocto, imx6

I intend to do native development (C and C++) and build using Cmake. I noticed that on adding

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += "nativesdk-cmake"    
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " tools-sdk tools-debug "
```

to the local conf file and build the image using

```
bitbake meta-ide-toolchain

bitbake <image> -c populate_sdk
```

it does not add CMAKE build tools to the target `/usr/bin`

How do I get CMAKE on the installed image on the target iMx6ULL platform so that I can build using CMAKE on the target itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yocto SDK with cmake toolchain file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964891/yocto-sdk-with-cmake-toolchain-file)

Comment: No, It does not the link you provided talks about building Yocto SDK for cross compiling on a host machine . I wish to compile on target device itself hence I need the tools baked into the image itself and not not external. Thank you .